# for_each over multiple containers

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

I have worked up an implementation of a `for_each` style function that can iterate over multiple containers at the same time.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

namespace detail
{

    //adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6894436/1865694
    template<std::size_t I = 0, typename FuncT, typename... Tp>
    inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
    tuple_for_each(std::tuple<Tp...> &, FuncT) 
    { }

    //adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6894436/1865694
    template<std::size_t I = 0, typename FuncT, typename... Tp>
    inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
    tuple_for_each(std::tuple<Tp...>& t, FuncT f)
    {
        f(std::get<I>(t));
        tuple_for_each<I + 1, FuncT, Tp...>(t, f);
    }

    //adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6894436/1865694
    template<std::size_t I = 0, typename FuncT, typename... Tp>
    inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), bool>::type
    tuple_compare_not_equal(std::tuple<Tp...> &,std::tuple<Tp...> &, FuncT)
    {
        return true;
    }

    //adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6894436/1865694
    template<std::size_t I = 0, typename FuncT, typename... Tp>
    inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), bool>::type
    tuple_compare_not_equal(std::tuple<Tp...>& t1,std::tuple<Tp...>& t2, FuncT f)
    {
        const bool b = f(std::get<I>(t1),std::get<I>(t2));
        return b && tuple_compare_not_equal<I + 1, FuncT, Tp...>(t1,t2, f);
    }

    //adapted from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence
    template<typename Func, typename Tup, std::size_t... index>
    decltype(auto) tuple_invoke_helper(Func&& func, Tup&& tup, std::index_sequence<index...>)
    {
        return func(std::get<index>(std::forward<Tup>(tup))...);
    }

    //adapted from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence
    template<typename Func, typename Tup>
    decltype(auto) tuple_invoke(Func&& func, Tup&& tup)
    {
        constexpr auto Size = std::tuple_size<typename std::decay<Tup>::type>::value;
        return tuple_invoke_helper(std::forward<Func>(func),
                             std::forward<Tup>(tup),
                             std::make_index_sequence<Size>{});
    }

}


template<typename F, typename... C>
auto multi_for_each(F&& f, C&&... c)
{
    using detail::tuple_for_each;
    using detail::tuple_invoke;
    using detail::tuple_compare_not_equal;


    //tuple of all begin iters
    auto begin = std::make_tuple(std::begin(std::forward<C&&>(c))...);
    //tuple of all end iters
    auto end   = std::make_tuple(std::end  (std::forward<C&&>(c))...);

    //tuple of iters to move
    auto iter  = begin;

    //helper lambda
    auto&& compare_not_equals = [](auto& _1, auto& _2)
    {
        return _1 != _2;
    };
    //helper lambda
    auto&& advance_1 = [](auto& i)
    {
        std::advance(i, 1);
    };


    while(tuple_compare_not_equal(iter,end,compare_not_equals))//while none of the iterators have reached their repective endsa
    {
        tuple_invoke(f, iter);//invoke the function
        tuple_for_each(iter,advance_1);//advance all iterators
    }

    //returns the distance traveled
    return std::distance(std::get<0>(begin), std::get<0>(iter));
}
```

Example `main`:

```
int main(int argc,char** argv){

    constexpr std::size_t N = 16;
    std::array<float, N> a1;
    std::array<float, N> a2;
    std::array<float, N> a3;

    //fill 
    std::size_t i=0;
    std::generate(a1.begin(), a1.end(), [&](){return i++;});
    std::generate(a2.begin(), a2.end(), [&](){return i++;});


    auto&& func = [](auto&& _1,auto&& _2,auto&& _3)
    {
        *_3= *_2 + *_1;
        std::cout<<*_1<<"\t"<<*_2<<"\t"<<*_3<<std::endl;
    };

    auto&& dist = multi_for_each(func,a1,a2,a3);

    std::cout<<"Iterators Moved by: "<<dist<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Example Output:

> 0  16  16
>
> 1  17  18
>
> 2  18  20
>
> 3  19  22
>
> 4  20  24
>
> 5  21  26
>
> 6  22  28
>
> 7  23  30
>
> 8  24  32
>
> 9  25  34
>
> 10 26  36
>
> 11 27  38
>
> 12 28  40
>
> 13 29  42
>
> 14 30  44
>
> 15 31  46
>
> Iterators Moved by: 16

I am looking for any issued that may come up based on this implementation and for anything that I can improve.

I did my best to avoid rolling my own helper functions. If there is anything in the standard library that I could substitute for anything I would love to know about it.

This version is designed around C++14 but I would also love to hear if C++17 is bringing anything that may be of use as well.